# ASP.NET Core Razor Page: Passing value from Foreach to a JavaScript function

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to pass the value from a C# object to a JavaScript function.
But I am getting an error:

```
@foreach (var Item in Model.Student)  
{
    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox(JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Item)))"/>
}
```

The `Model.Student` property returns a `Student` object, which is defined as follows:

```cs
public class Student 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string name { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Without knowing any details about your `Model.Student` property's type, I'm afraid there's not much we can help with. It seems you're hoping to deserialize it into a JSON string, which your `onclick` handler will then convert to a JSON object. What would be useful is to provide us with details about that type, as well as what the output actually looks like.

Comment: Some unsolicited feedback on your code: Typically, in C#, property names will be `PascalCase`—and, thus, your `name` property should be `Name`. Conversely, local variables are typically `camelCase`—and, thus, your `Item` variable should be `item`. This doesn't impact the functionality of your code and is outside the scope of your question, but it's worth being aware of to ensure you're following well-established industry standards. (There are plenty of other areas that are a matter of stylistic preference and vary from developer-to-developer, but these are pretty much universal.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to do three things to resolve this issue:

1. Serialize your `Student` object (`Item`) to JSON using `Json.Serialize()`,
2. Encode your JSON as a JavaScript string using `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()`, and
3. Wrap your JSON in apostrophes so that `JSON.parse()` is correctly interpreting it as a string.

Your final Razor markup should look like the following:

```html
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox(JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Json.Serialize(Item).ToString()))'))"/>
```

Continue reading for a deeper understanding of how to troubleshoot these types of issues in the future, as well as why each one of these steps is necessary.

#### Debugging

Before diving in, it's worth taking a step back to revisit some troubleshooting principles. Remember that ASP.NET Core MVC is simply rendering an HTML page. After that, it's up to the browser to parse and execute both the HTML and the JavaScript. When you're combining Razor, HTML, and JavaScript in the same line, but only looking at the errors generated by JavaScript, it's easy to miss the underlying issue. Given this, what you want to do is view the source code in your browser to see what HTML is being generated.

#### Issue #1: Serializing Classes

The most immediate issue is that when you call `@Html.Raw(Item)`, the `Item`'s `ToString()` method is going to be called to create a string representation of your `Student` object. If your `Student` object is a class, this will just be the fully-qualified name of the class (e.g., `MyNamespace.Student`).

This will output something like:

```html
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox(JSON.parse(MyNamespace.Student))"/>
```

That's obviously not valid JSON, nor does it include any of your data. To resolve this, you need to wrap the call to `Item` in `Json.Serialize()`, which will *serialize* it from a C# object to a JSON string:

```html
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox(JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Item))))"/>
```

This will output something closer to what you want:

```html
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox(JSON.parse({"Id"=1,"name":"John"}))"/>
```

#### Issue #2: Encoding JSON

If you attempt to execute the above code, you're going to encounter a JavaScript error, such as the following:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Do you see the problem? The quote around `Id` is going to close your `onclick` handler, resulting in malformed markup. From the browser's perspective, it ends up seeing the following attributes, trailed by invalid markup:

- id: `btnAdd`
- type: `button`
- value: `Add`
- onclick: `AddTextBox(JSON.parse('{`

To remedy this, you need to encode the JSON string so that it can be embedded within a JavaScript call. Fortunately, ASP.NET Core supplies us with the `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()` method that does just that:

```html
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox(JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Json.Serialize(Item).ToString()))))"/>
```

> *Note:* The `JavaScriptStringEncode()` method requires a string, so we need to call `ToString()` on the `Json.Serialize()` call, which otherwise outputs an `IHtmlContent` object.

This will now output something like the following:

```html
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox(JSON.parse({\&quot;Id\&quot;=1,\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;John\&quot;}))"/>
```

#### Issue #3: Converting to a JSON object

There are still problems here. The `JSON.parse()` method expects a *string*, but we're passing it raw JSON notation. As such, if you execute this code, you'll now receive a variation on the original error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

This can be resolved by simply wrapping the JSON in apostrophes, denoting that it's a string:

```html
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox(JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Json.Serialize(Item).ToString()))'))"/>
```

This will now output something like the following:

```html
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox(JSON.parse('{\&quot;Id\&quot;=1,\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;John\&quot;}'))"/>
```

If you click on this element, this should finally work—assuming, of course, your `AddTextBox()` is functioning correctly.

#### Conclusion

As mentioned at the top, when working with Razor, HTML, and JavaScript, you really need to pay close attention to what HTML is being rendered from the Razor page, prior to it being parsed by the browser or executed by the JavaScript engine. In this case, most of these issues stem from malformed markup that either the browser or the JavaScript engine aren't able to properly parse.

Comment: I am getting this error

VM1659:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @John1985: My original answer was not fully tested, and was not only missing a step, but was also referencing an out-of-date function. I do apologize for the confusion that must have caused. I've rewritten my answer to address these two issues, and tested it in ASP.NET Core 5 to confirm it works. Please give it a try and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @John1985: Checking in. Did this update resolve your errors?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, yes it is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: @John1985: Please be sure to accept this answer when you get an opportunity by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer.